# Linking form to user meta fields

Tags: plugins, login, forms, user-registration, user-meta

I currently have my login page set up to allow sign up through google. Immediately after a successful sign up I'm looking to set up a redirect to a form where the user can enter additional details and these are saved within predefined user meta fields.

I know how to set up the fields using ACF or Pods. Are there free plugins available which can link a form to the meta fields? I'm fairly new to developing hooks but if there's a way of doing this with code I would appreciate any advice on which files I should be looking to edit and what commands to make use of.

Comment: Most of the major form plugins (Gravity, CF7) have various ways to extend functionality.  This might get you headed in the right direction if using CF7: https://contactform7.com/2020/07/28/accessing-user-input-data/#more-36856

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track.